# Uploading a new version of a pdf file

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, versioning, update

I know how to upload a new version of a document in SharePoint. However, I want to upload the new version of a PDF or a zip file.

Is it also possible to have different version for non-office documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer to your question is **Yes**.

SharePoint will retain the different versions of the PDF/Zip file. SharePoint doesn't care what type of file it is when it comes to keeping file versions.

**Update**:

You need to enable **Versioning** for your library from `Library settings --> Versioning Settings`.

Then you can upload a your updated file with same name and replace the existing file in document library. You can check all version of you file from **Version history**.

Check below official documentation for enabling versioning and how to check the version history:

[Enable and configure versioning for a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37).

Comment: But how I have to upload the new version to the share point?

Comment: Check updated answer. you can upload a your updated file with same name and replace the existing file in document library. Then you will be able to see all versions of your file from **Version history**.